# how to output individual files to a specified directory for cljsbuild

Tags: clojurescript

Using cljsbuild, I can compile all my .cljs files to one file. However, I wish to be able to pick a directory for output and have each .cljs file compile into its own .js file. How can this be specified?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'multiple build configurations': cljsbuild accepts a vector of configurations for `:builds` key, each element of which defines rules for compiling separate .js file (more info could be found in [lein-cljsbuild README](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild)). Simple example:

```
:cljsbuild 
{:builds 
 [;; Config for first .js file
  {:source-paths ["dir-with-cljs-for-first-js"]
   :compiler {:output-to "dir-for-js/first.js"}
  ;; Config for second .js file
  {:source-paths ["dir-with-cljs-for-second-js"]
   :compiler {:output-to "dir-for-js/second.js"}}]}
```

Comment: how would I get a seperate .js file for every .clj file in "dir-with-cljs-for-first-js"?

Comment: In this example two .js files would be compiled: one from .cljs sources in "dir-with-cljs-for-first-js", second - from sources in "dir-with-cljs-for-second-js". There is no way to to create .js file for each file in directory ("dir-with-cljs-for-first-js"), but you could put every .cljs in a separate sub-directory (for instance, "dir-with-cljs-for-first-js/1", "dir-with-cljs-for-first-js/2", etc.) and manually specify a build configuration for each such sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the :output-dir option. My cljsbuild looks like this:

```
:cljsbuild
  {:builds
   [{:id "dev"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :compiler {:output-to  "resources/public/js/site.js"
                :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                :source-map true :optimizations :none }}
    {:id "main"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :compiler {:pretty-print false
                :output-to "resources/public/js/site.js"
                :source-map "resources/public/js/site.js.map"
                :optimizations :advanced}}]}
```

With this config, and **without site.js already compiled/up to date**,  `lein cljsbuild once dev` or `lein cljsbuild auto dev` will compile site.js, then see it's dependencies aren't compiled and go compile them, along with their [sourcemaps](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Source-maps). If site.js is compiled and up to date, cljsbuild will think there's nothing to be done and terminate before generating source maps, etc.

I also highly recommend [lein figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) for cljs development, and remember to enable sourcemaps.