# lein-cljsbuild source-cljs dir -> output-js dir?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, cljsbuild

Looking at cljsbuild doc
https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild

```
:cljsbuild {
    :builds [{
        ; The path to the top-level ClojureScript source directory:
        :source-paths ["src-cljs"]

        :compiler {
          :output-to "war/javascripts/main.js"  
            ; default: target/cljsbuild-main.js
```

it requires

:source-paths as a directory

:output-to as a js-file

Why not source dir -> output dir??

How do we manage many source files to be compiled to many output files?

Is there any configuration to map *.cljs @sourceDir -> *.js @targetDir ?

Comment: Why do you want multiple output files?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to get multiple output files, just [use multiple builds](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#multiple-build-configurations)

Keep in mind the code is meant to run through the Google Closure compiler, which not only reduces the file count down to 1 (which is more efficient for the browser to download), but also removes a huge amount of redundancy in the code.  It also ensures that files are loaded in the correct order.

If you don't want any inlining, you can set the `:optimizations` option to `:none` (as compared to `:whitespace`, `:simple`, or `:advanced`.  That may get you something closer to what you want.  Make sure you check the target directory for temporary files which may be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the author, but I imagine it has to do with a couple things.

1. Having a single output makes things like cljsbuild auto more manageable.
2. Well I can see some limited use case for multiple input paths, multiple output files seems counter to browser efficiency? Where you basically want a single highly optimized .js file for optimum download speeds.

If you needed multiple .js files from multiple .cljs builds that aren't really related, that's essentially a different project already.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need an :output-to, but I think you're looking for the [:output-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939816/how-to-output-individual-files-to-a-specified-directory-for-cljsbuild/28262024#28262024) option.